# How well-supported is the Canon CanoScan LiDE110?

Tags: resolution, canon, scanning, sane, dpi

On the [list of supported SANE devices](http://www.sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html) the scanner is listed as fully supported but it says:

> resolution from 75 to 2400 dpi

[Here](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16838111056) is a link to Newegg's item listing, where it lists the optical resolution as:

> 2400 x 4800dpi

I'm a bit confused here - Is SANE's support not up to the full potential of the scanner? Am I reading this wrong or is the list just not specifying enough information to me?

Comment: Just to follow up, I bought the scanner and it works wonderfully. I did have to update my sane libs, however, for it to be detected. You can find the ppa at https://launchpad.net/~robert-ancell/+archive/sane-backends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am pretty sure that is a typo in the SANE list because for what i have seen, some of the scanners there like some Stylus, Scanjet and maybe others do not appear in the list updated as they should be. I have in the place i work several of them and they work 100% good but in the SANE page they do not mention this. Am guessing the page is old or when they did the update they forgot some of them. So the safest bet is your LiDE 110 will function perfectly.

Comment: Well, they DO have it listed as "complete". Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just to add, 2 of the Stylus i work with were "Good" a year or two ago but they worked flawlessly. So am guessing they test a lot a product for a very long time before saying it works 100%. So a product can work 100% for us for a long time before it appears in that page as 100% working.