# Canon LIDE 110 - lsusb sane-find-scanner

Tags: usb, scanning, canon, sane

I'd like to use a Canon LIDE 110 scanner under Ubuntu 10.

Here are the results of lsusb and sane-find-scanner:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 1532:001a Razer USA, Ltd 
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 003: ID 0471:0602 Philips ATI Remote Wonder II Input Device
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 1532:0019 Razer USA, Ltd 
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 004: ID 0dc6:5300 Precision Squared Technology Corp. 
Bus 006 Device 003: ID 0dc6:5000 Precision Squared Technology Corp. 
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 1532:001b Razer USA, Ltd 
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 04a9:1909 Canon, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

And

```
$ sudo sane-find-scanner 

  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure tha
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

  # No USB scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel driver for your USB host controller and have setu
  # the USB system correctly. See man sane-usb for details.
  # SANE has been built without libusb support. This may be a reason
  # for not detecting USB scanners. Read README for more details.

  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.
```

Comment: Hi Glide what version of Ubuntu are you using 10.04, 10.10, or 11.04

Comment: also this answer (http://askubuntu.com/questions/33564/how-well-supported-is-the-canon-canoscan-lide110) advices a different ppa to the one mentioned in the Ubuntu forum post you left a message on. Instead it suggests you use https://launchpad.net/~robert-ancell/+archive/sane-backends as it has been updated for all versions 10.04 to 11.04.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 10.04. I have gitted the last sane software. I have followed the pretty wiki article http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/scanner_canoscan_lide for installing Canon Lide products but at least I should be able to see it with sane-find-scanner, that I'm not.

Comment: I just installed Oneiric and all my problems are gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All my problems were gone after Oneiric (11.10) installation.

Actually I didn't test with 11.04.